# Junk characters being printed with tee command

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

Script I'm utilizing is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

lla=$(top -n 1 | grep "load average" | awk '{print $13,$14,$15}')
mem_usage=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}')
now=`date`
cur_time=$(echo $now | awk '{print $4}')

for i in {1..60}
do
        echo "System Performance Statistics at: "$cur_time | tee -a hp.txt
        echo "Linux Load Average: "$lla | tee -a hp.txt
        echo "Memory Usage: "$mem_usage | tee -a hp.txt
        echo "" | tee -a hp.txt

        sleep 3
done
```

Results:

```
System Performance Statistics at: 19:00:29
Linux Load Average: 0.13, 0.11, 0.14^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[K
Memory Usage: 82.7672
```

Standard out isn't showing any garbage characters at all. What do I need to change?

Comment: If you replace `grep "load average" | awk '{print $13,$14,$15}'` with `awk '/load average/ {print $13,$14,$15}'` in the script does the problem go away?

Comment: I found the issue. I had to add a -b to the top command in order to prevent special characters from being output.

Comment: Have you thought of parsing the `uptime` command instead? Or since you're in Linux, perhaps parsing the content of `/proc/loadavg` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added -b to top command and it works.

From `man top`:

> **-b**  :Batch-mode operation
>
> Starts top in Batch mode, which could be useful for sending output
>   from top to other programs or to a file.  In this mode, top will not
>   accept input and runs until the iterations limit you've set with the
>   `-n' command-line option or until killed.